# How to Change the background image size in custom css?

Tags: css

**i was trying like that,that is not working**

.login{

```
margin-top: 70px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
background-image: url(../../Images/bg5.png);
background-size:0 500px;
width: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the error. You have to add width value to background-size since your using
two-value syntax (first value: width of the image, second value: height)

e.g. background-size:300px 500px;

Visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Also remove width property.

Comment: Pretty sure it is set by the container it is in, that is why you have options like stretch and cover! Check out https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp